# Testing authentication UI in selenium

Tags: python, authentication, selenium, pylons

I am using selenium with pylons to test user interactions. Everything was fine until I added testing for an authentication UI -- a login screen with user name and password. It appears that Chrome (the browser I am using under selenium) is popping up a dialog to request whether to store the credentials. All the tests fail after this point.

Does anyone have any pointers on using selenium with authentication/UIs that may pop up dialog boxes? I am aware of [this selenium warning](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SEL/Selenium+Core+FAQ#SeleniumCoreFAQ-Ican%27tinteractwithapopupdialog.Myteststopsinitstracks!). "Don't do this. Do this other thing instead" would be an acceptable answer.

---

project/tests/lib/selenium/login_page.py

```
"""
LoginPage represents the page where users are authenticated for the application
"""


class LoginPage(object):
    """This is the LoginPage class."""

    login = '/authentication/login'
    logout = '/authentication/logout'
    home = '/home'

    def __init__(self, browser):
        self._browser = browser

    def goto_login(self, baseurl):
        return self._browser.go_to(baseurl + self.login)

    def goto_logout(self, baseurl):
        return self._browser.go_to(baseurl + self.logout)

    def goto_home(self, baseurl):
        return self._browser.go_to(baseurl + self.home)

    def enter_credentials(self, username, password):
        element_by_id = self._browser.get_element_by_id
        element_by_id("login").value = username
        element_by_id("password").value = password

    def submit_form(self):
        element = self._browser.get_element_by_id('submit')
        return self._browser.click(element)
```

project/tests/selenium/test_login_page.py

```
"""Tests the login page."""

import nose.tools as nt
from nose.plugins.skip import SkipTest

from assess.tests.selenium import SeleniumTestBase
from assess.tests.lib.selenium.login_page import LoginPage


class TestLoginPage(SeleniumTestBase):
    """Tests the login page."""

    def _login_page(self):
        return self.baseurl + '/authentication/login'

    def setUp(self):
        nt.set_trace()
        super(TestLoginPage, self).setUp()
        self.page = LoginPage(self.browser)

    def tearDown(self):
        super(TestLoginPage, self).tearDown()
        self.page = None

    def test_login_page_fail(self):
        # Logout before beginning test
        self.page.goto_logout(self.baseurl)

        self.page.goto_login(self.baseurl)
        nt.assert_true(self.browser.get_url().startswith(self._login_page()))
        self.page.enter_credentials('foo', 'random')
        self.page.submit_form()

    def test_login_page_success(self):
        # Logout before beginning test
        self.page.goto_logout(self.baseurl)

        self.page.goto_login(self.baseurl)
        nt.assert_true(self.browser.get_url().startswith(self._login_page()))
        self.page.enter_credentials('user', 'good-password')
        self.page.submit_form()
```

project/templates/login.html.mako

```
<%inherit file="/layout.html.mako" />

${h.stylesheet_link('login.css')}

<form action="/__do_login" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <p>
        <label for="login">User name</label><br />
        <input id="login" name="login" type="text" maxlength="40" value="" />
        </p>
        <p>
        <label for="password">Password</label><br />
        <input id="password" name="password" type="password" maxlength="40" value="" />
        </p>
        <p class="submit">
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

etc/who.ini

```
[general]
request_classifier = repoze.who.classifiers:default_request_classifier
challenge_decider = repoze.who.classifiers:default_challenge_decider

[identifiers]
plugins = foo
          friendly_form;browser

[authenticators]
plugins = foo 

[challengers]
plugins = friendly_form;browser
          foo

[plugin:foo]
use = ...
host = ...
logout_path_regex = /authentication/logout
httponly = True

[plugin:friendly_form]
use = repoze.who.plugins.friendlyform:FriendlyFormPlugin
login_form_url = /authentication/login
login_handler_path = /__do_login
post_login_url = /home
logout_handler_path = /authentication/logout
post_logout_url = /authentication/login
```

project/config/routing.py

```
def make_map(config):
    """Create, configure and return the routes Mapper"""
    mapper = Mapper(directory=config['pylons.paths']['controllers'],
                 always_scan=config['debug'])
    mapper.minimization = False
    mapper.explicit = False

    # The ErrorController route (handles 404/500 error pages); it should
    # likely stay at the top, ensuring it can always be resolved
    mapper.connect('/error/{action}', controller='error')
    mapper.connect('/error/{action}/{sid}', controller='error')

    # CUSTOM ROUTES HERE

...
    mapper.connect('/authentication/login',
                   controller='authentication',
                   action='index')
    mapper.connect('/authentication/logout',
                   controller='authentication',
                   action='logout')
```

project/controllers/authentication.py

```
"""
This module contains the login controller.
"""

import logging

from pylons.controllers.util import redirect
from pylons import url, tmpl_context as c, request

from project.lib.base import BaseController
from project.lib.authorize import user_is_authenticated

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class AuthenticationController(BaseController):
    """ This controller serves the login page."""
    template = '/login.html.mako'

    def index(self):
        return self.render(self.template)

    def validate(self):
        """ render a login page if we're not logged in """
        c.came_from = request.params.get("came_from", url("home"))

        # If we're already authenticated, redirect us to where we started.
        if user_is_authenticated():
            msg = "User is authenticated: redirecting to %s" % c.came_from
            logger.info(msg)
            redirect(c.came_from)

        msg = "User is not authenticated: rendering %s" % self.template
        logger.info(msg)
        return self.render(self.template)
```

project/lib/authorize.py

```
''' Helper functions for the authorization and authentication mechanisms. '''
from pylons import request
from decorator import decorator
from pylons.controllers.util import abort


def user_is_authenticated():
    """ Returns True if is authenticated, else returns False.
    """
    identity = request.environ.get('repoze.who.identity')
    return identity and 'xxx' in identity


@decorator
def authenticated(func, *args, **kwargs):
    """ Check if is authenticated.  If not authenticated, abort with
        401 status.
    """
    if not user_is_authenticated():
        abort(401, 'You are not authenticated')
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Doesn't Chrome usually open a bar at the top pf the page with "Save password" or "Never for this site" buttons? Those are native controls, so there's not much to do. Have you found a site that pops up a blocking dialog?

Comment: It's not a blocking dialog, but selenium appears to make a new tab in chrome, and all subsequent tests fail because selenium can't find buttons to press, input elements to enter text in, etc. I believe that on my dev machine, I must have said "Never for this site" (and I don't even think that helps), but the test build server that we run on definitely doesn't. All really annoying.

Comment: That'd be a new problem, could you paste the relevant code into your question. I assume you're using Selenium-RC and python?

Comment: Added code. The general gist is that pylons uses repoze.who in the middleware to do authentication. Code in who.ini plugs into the url. Code in controllers.py associates url with controller code. Controller code uses repoze.who primitives to determine authentication. Selenium tests use web primitives to drive web UI when login screen is shown, producing authenticated user when used with correct credentials. Result, though, is that selenium puts extra tab in chrome, making UI elements in further tests inaccessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should use a profile for your tests and in this profile you should specify to never ask for saving the credentials. Unfortunately it is impossible to specify a customized Chrome profile with Selenium 1, but it is possible to do for Firefox in Selenium 1 or move to Selenium 2 (WebDriver) - see [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/selenium-users/browse_thread/thread/517d599ebadbf7c4) for more information

Comment: @hughdbrown, Strange, I am opening the link with no problems - http://groups.google.com/group/selenium-users/browse_thread/thread/517d599ebadbf7c4

Selenium is starting Chrome with a new clean profile each and every
time you use it. Selenium 1 does not offer a mechanism for overriding
this. Selenium 2's ChromeDriver, however, can use an example profile.